# While opening the live server "Developer failed to load source map"

Tags: web, web-development-server

While opening the live server in Google Chrome, I get this error:

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb/js/companionBubble.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```